# Django POST request always return 400 even the method is successful

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am working on a Django project and I am making a simple API for creating users. The problem is, the post request can be performed successfully as I check the backends. However, it always returns the 400 error code as the last line shown.

My views.py code is as following:

```
class createUserView(APIView):
    serializer_class = CreateUserSerializer
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data = request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            name = serializer.data.get('name')
            age = serializer.data.get('age')
            queryset = user.objects.filter(name=name)
            if queryset.exists():
                print("already exists")
                new_user = user(name=name, age=age)
                # new_user.save()
                return Response(userSerializer(new_user).data, status=status.HTTP_200)
            else:
                new_user = user(name = name,age=age)
                new_user.save()
                return Response(userSerializer(new_user).data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response({'Bad Request': 'Invalid data...'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

my models.py code is as following:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class user(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True,null=False, default=None)
    age = models.IntegerField(null=False, default=1)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I think the problem is in the views.py. Whenever the code enters the user.save() block, the return statement does not work so the code keep running until the last line.

Comment: Maybe the serializer is never valid ? (at post begin)
Are you sure to enter in the first if condition in the view ?

Comment: Yes, it certainly enters the first if. When I post on that page, I can see from the backend that the data was saved successfully.

Comment: Hum. What does the 400 response contains ? 'Invalid data...' ?

Comment: Yea, just as shown in the last line; i just leave them for debug purpose